Python SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate
I'm running the below code while I am learning python with mlb stats api installed.
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import statsapi

box_score = statsapi.boxscore(565997)
print(box_score)

I'm getting an error that I am unable to locate the issuer certificate SSL when trying to access this, update Conda, or just about anything else. I've tried upgrading certifi; I've also seen to use ssl_verify .crt, but U can't find my crt (I've also seen similar comments about a .pem)
As above, I've tried to verify = false, but I don't want to continue with that due to safety concerns.

are you using python on a Mac? if yes, try to run the Install Certificates.command script inside the Applications\Python3.x folder.

@Razzer I’m using windows and anaconda/spyder

The statsapi python library visits https://statsapi.mlb.com, which is secured with the GTS4 root certificate. In turn, it uses the requests library, and requests uses the certifi library for CA certificates. You should check the versions of all these libraries and make sure they are up-to-date.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk I updated them all and am still getting that error. Similar errors with Conda and pybaseball.
